# How can test if an image is onto another in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have two images, as explained in the following XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApplicationGestureKinect.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" MinWidth="1024" MaxWidth="1024" MinHeight="768" MaxHeight="768">
    <Grid Background="Black">

        <Image x:Name="img1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Source="photos/01.jpg" Height="200" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="9.577"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>

        <Image x:Name="cursorRight" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="757,133,0,0" Width="48" Height="48" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Source="cursors/right_open.png" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the following image shows how this appear:

[image: The result of the above XAML code]

I need a way to test, from C# code, if the image called `cursorRight` is onto the area covered by the image called `img1`, after the transformation.

How could I do? I thought about some consideration on the bounding boxes of the two images, but while for the `cursorRight` image, could be acceptable to consider the bounding box, this doesn't seem to be a good choice for the other image......

EDIT: The following images show four examples of how I want to do:

- cursor on the image:

  [image]

  [image]
- cursor not on the image:

  [image]

  [image]

SOLUTION: The following code is what I used in order to solve the above problem. I considered the bounding box of the cursor rather than the exact shape of it.

```
    private bool isOn(Image img1, Image img2)
    {
        if (img1 == null || img1.Visibility != System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
        {
            return false;
        }

        double img1_topLeft_X = img1.Margin.Left;
        double img1_topLeft_Y = img1.Margin.Top;
        double img1_bottomRight_X = img1_topLeft_X + img1.Width;
        double img1_bottomRight_Y = img1_topLeft_Y + img1.Height;

        Point img1_topLeft = new Point(img1_topLeft_X, img1_topLeft_Y);
        Point img1_bottomRight = new Point(img1_bottomRight_X, img1_bottomRight_Y);

        HitTestResult result_topLeft = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(img2.Parent as Grid, img1_topLeft);
        HitTestResult result_bottomRight = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(img2.Parent as Grid, img1_bottomRight);

        if (result_topLeft != null && result_bottomRight != null)
        {
            if (result_topLeft.VisualHit.GetType() == typeof(Image) && result_bottomRight.VisualHit.GetType() == typeof(Image) &&
                (result_topLeft.VisualHit as Image).Name.Equals(img2.Name) && (result_bottomRight.VisualHit as Image).Name.Equals(img2.Name))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

However, in this way the cursor is ONTO the image only if the bounding box of it is TOTALLY onto the image. It's not exactly what I needed, but since it works pretty well, I decided to use this method.

Comment: not sure if it would work so i add it as a comment : try firing an event on hover(IsMouseOver) if you have multiple images wire the events to the same methood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option not quite would be to use the `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(...)` methods to check if points overlapped each other.  You can read more about it works [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: This is the simplier solution ;) Thank you very much. An useful and more extended example of how to use `HitTest` can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308448/is-a-usercontrol-not-in-the-hittestresult).

Answer (score 1):

Use bounding rectangle for your cursor and a "bounding polygon" that defines the area of your larger image and then use polygon intersection algorithm (one explanation [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15573/2D-Polygon-Collision-Detection)) to solve your problem.

Comment: This could be a working solution, but I think that the method proposed by [Steve Van Treeck](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1697393/steve-van-treeck) is more simple and equivalently effective.